# NetLogo - directed movements of turtles within a specific area

Tags: netlogo

I wanna make turtles do directed movements in NetLogo. Let's say we have a specific area as *blue-patches* where turtles can only survive within this area. They cannot escape from this area. And for each turtle it wanna move toward to lower local density with a specific speed (a minimum number of turtles within an area with a specific radius).

I generate a variable for patches as *local-density*.
and use

```
let ideal-destination min-one-of blue-patches [ count turtles in-radius 5 ]
face ideal-destination
```

to get the direction of movement. But the problem is with a specific speed they can escape from the constrained area. How can I let them stop at the edge of the constrained area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For moving turtles in a constraint area with a specific speed, we can use *patch-ahead* to check:

```
ifelse patch-ahead speed != nobody
  [ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead high-speed = white ;;the color of outside of the area
    [ fd 0 ]
    [ fd speed ] ]
  [ fd 0 ]
```